# Tumblr guest blog profile image within blog

Tags: blogs, tumblr, profile

I'm looking to add in the image of a guest poster into the main blog. Basically {PortraitURL-30} for the guest user.

[image]

In the blog I want to pull in the person silhouette, I can't seem to find the code anywhere if I use {PortraitURL-30} it'll just bring back the orange profile image.

All the necessary tickboxes for allowing thumbnails and such has been ticked, I've spent the last couple of days speaking to tumblr support with them just coming back saying they don't offer technical support.

The class for the person silhouette is post_sub_avatar, I've been looking high and low for something along the lines of

---

{PostSubAvatar-30} or something but I can't seem to find it!

Any help would be appreciated!
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 {block:GroupMembers}
      {GroupMemberPortraitURL-30}
 {/block:GroupMembers}
```